# Como faço para instalar o pacote Chromium em Delphi?

Tags: html5, delphi, navegador-de-internet, delphi-xe6, object-pascal

Eu estava usando o componente TWebBrowser que é baseado no Internet Explorer, porém tenho notado que ele roda de forma desfigurada as páginas HTML5, ouvi falar no pacote do FireFox, mas ele não rodou no Delphi e demonstrou-se ser bem pesado, então minha ultima alternativa foi o pacote do Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independente da versão do IE que vc tiver na maquina o windows sempre irá usar o IE6 dentro de qualquer aplicação desktop que vc colocar um webbrowser. Isso quer dizer que vc não terá vários suportes que as versões mais novar do IE tem, como suporte a JQuery ou mesmo Json.
Para resolver este problema vc deve fazer uma alteração no registro do windows para seu executável, dizendo que quer usar a versão mais atual do browser.
Crie um arquivo .reg com a seguinte estrutura:

> REGEDIT4
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
>   "MeuExecutavel.exe"=dword:0

Já utilizei o chromium no Delphi como alternativa a uns 2 anos atraz, e ele era muuuuito instavel.

Comment: Na verdade é o IE 7 Standars Mode não IE 6. E para configurar o modo de compatibilidade do IE 8 o valor da chave é `"MyApplication.exe" = dword 8888 (Hex: 0x22B8)` e não zero. Não sei onde você leu sobre o IE6 mas parece que é incorreto. Minhas referências são: [esse link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/18/webbrowser-control-rendering-modes-in-ie8.aspx) e [esse outro link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx)